# UnicodeDecodeError with MySQL to Cloud Storage Bucket Airflow DAG

Tags: python, mysql, json, utf-8, airflow

I have created a DAG that extracts MySQL data from a database and loads it to Cloud storage then BigQuery as json files.

The DAG works for certain tables but not all, because it can't decode certain characters in the tables. It's quite a lot of data so I can't pin point exactly where the error or invalid characters are.

I've tried changing my database, table and column character sets from utf8 to utf8mb4. This didn't help.

I've also tried calling encoding='utf-8' as well as 'iso-8859-1', how ever I don't think I am calling them correctly because I have been doing this with my connection and I still get the same error.

I'm running Python 2.7.12 and airflow  v1.8.0

Update: After reading this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Common+Pitfalls which suggests using a connection string that defines charset, ex.:sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow@localhost:3306/airflow?charset=utf8

How would this be done with a Cloud SQL instance?

```
podio_connections = [
    'mysql_connection'
]

podio_tables = [
     'finance_banking_details',
     'finance_goods_invoices',
]

default_args = {
    'owner': 'xxxxxx',
    'start_date': datetime(2018,1,11),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('mysql_to_bigquery', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily')

slack_notify = SlackAPIPostOperator(
    task_id='slack_notify',
    token='xxxxxx',
    channel='data-status',
    username='airflow',
    text='Successfully performed Podio ETL operation',
    dag=dag)

for connection in podio_connections:
    for table in podio_tables:
        extract = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
            task_id="extract_mysql_%s_%s"%(connection,table),
            mysql_conn_id=connection,
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_connection',
            sql="SELECT *, '%s' as source FROM podiodb.%s"%(connection,table),
            bucket='podio-reader-storage',
            filename="%s/%s/%s{}.json"%(connection,table,table),            
            schema_filename="%s/schemas/%s.json"%(connection,table),
        dag=dag)

        load = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
            task_id="load_bg_%s_%s"%(connection,table),
            bigquery_conn_id='gcp_connection',
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcp_connection',
            bucket='podio-reader-storage',
            #destination_project_dataset_table="podio-data.%s.%s"%(connection,table),
            destination_project_dataset_table = "podio-data.podio_data1.%s"%(table),
            source_objects=["%s/%s/%s*.json"%(connection,table,table)],
            schema_object="%s/schemas/%s.json"%(connection,table),
            source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
            write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            dag=dag)

        load.set_upstream(extract)
        slack_notify.set_upstream(load)
```

> [2018-01-12 15:36:10,221] {models.py:1417} ERROR - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 36: invalid start byte
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
>       result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 91, in execute
>       files_to_upload = self._write_local_data_files(cursor)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.py", line 136, in _write_local_data_files
>       json.dump(row_dict, tmp_file_handle)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 189, in dump
>       for chunk in iterable:
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 434, in _iterencode
>       for chunk in _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 390, in _iterencode_dict
>       yield _encoder(value)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 36: invalid start byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`96` is latin1 hex for "en-dash".  Either change the data to be utf8, or change the connection to MySQL to say you are using charset latin1.